# Two approaches to write stream?

Tags: c#

Here is two types of stream write process I often see.
Delegates consumation to upper layer:

```
public Stream OpenWrite()
{
    return File.OpenWrite(/*...*/); //this is example method invokation
}
//...
using(var output = OpenWrite())
{
    input.CopyTo(output);
}
```

Forcefully consumes stream:

```
public void WriteAll(Stream input)
{
    using(input)
    using(var output = File.OpenWrite())//this is example method invokation
    {
        input.CopyTo(output)
    }
}
```

Whilst *WriteAll* can be easily implemented through *OpenWrite* as extension method:

```
public void WriteAll(Stream input)
{
    using(input)
    using(var output = OpenWrite())
    {
        input.CopyTo(output)
    }
}
```

Can *OpenWrite* be implemented through *WriteAll* in this concrete scenario?

```
public Stream OpenWrite()
{
    return /*some produccer/consumer stream ? */
}
```

Im asking because I need to solve similar task of converting forcefull consumation to lazy one.

Comment: Both yere are non-lazy if I understand it correctly. The above only encapsulates the `File.OpenWrite`.

Comment: Well, not exactly, as I stated this is an example, before Write is invoked on stream - nothing happens. Before this happens it is just handler passed from place to place.

Comment: @eocron "before Write is invoked on stream nothing happens. " - this is not true, `Stream` is an abstract class and implementations can behave as they wish during construction or in their virtual methods. e.g. compare NetworkStream and FileStream and MemoryStream.

Comment: Yeap, I know, but we are not talking about concrete implementation, we can discuss how transform non-lazy ctr of FileStream to lazy one, but in other topic. Im talking about consumation types.

Comment: @eocron: what I mean is that encapsulating it in a method does not make it lazy. There is - afaik - only one way here to make it lazy: that is using an indirectionn over the `Stream` and thus opening it when it is actually used.

Comment: Yeah, wrong words chosen by me, I don't care about lazynes of stream implementation, if I care I just wrap it in LazyStream, fixed it in question. Thanks, but this doesn't ask the question.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your question is? I did not understand it but it seems interesting :)

Comment: I will ask this question later. Behavior I want implemented through BlockingCollection, Stream and separate task. Basically it is simple producer/consumer problem only on stream.